# How to check whether the string has a starting character is special characters : javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do we find if the starting character of a string has some special characters ?

The string can start with alphanumeric but should not start with any special characters.

If the string starts with special characters including space than it should alert the user that the input is invalid.

Comment: What is a special character for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this, by [testing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) whether the first character of the string is in the accepted range of `[A-Za-z0-9]`:

```
var s = "_whatever string_";

if(!/^[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(s)) {
    alert ("Invalid string");
}
```

Comment: @RobG `\W` allows underscores though.

Comment: The confusion caused by `\W` in this post is one of the reasons that I would prefer the more explicit `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Also, it's more readable for less regex-savvy developers that may have to maintain the application in the future.

Comment: thanks for the post, the string can have anything but it should not start with any special characters.

Comment: @Anto The question becomes then: what do you consider to be a special character? Where I am, 酒 is not a special character, but for you it probably is.